# running mysql query on Laravel `DB::Raw`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.6

I have a MYSQL query that i need to run on Laravel 5.6 query builder. my query is

```
SELECT paper_id,user_id,COUNT(payments.user_id),users.district
FROM payments
LEFT JOIN users ON payments.user_id = users.id
WHERE payments.paper_id=3
GROUP BY users.district HAVING COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0;
```

I have tried running this on Laravel `DB::Raw` with this code

```
$data=DB::Raw('SELECT paper_id,user_id,COUNT(payments.user_id),users.district
                    FROM payments
                    LEFT JOIN users ON payments.user_id = users.id
                    WHERE payments.paper_id='.$paper_id.'
                    GROUP BY users.district HAVING 
                    COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0 
                    ');
```

as well as through this code

```
$data2=DB::table('payments')
                    ->leftJoin('users','payments.user_id','users.id')
                    ->select('paper_id','user_id','users.district',
                      DB::Raw('COUNT(payments.user_id)'))
                    ->where('payments.paper_id',$paper_id)
                    ->groupBy('users.district')
                    ->select(DB::Raw('HAVING COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0'))
                    ->get();
```

Error I get on `$data` (first query) query

```
[{}]
```

i get an empty response

Error I get on `$data2 (second query) query

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
>       in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
>       version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0 from 
>       payments left join users on payments at line 1 (SQL: select HAVING 
>       COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0 from payments left join users on 
>       payments.user_id = users.id where payments.paper_id = 1 group by 
>       users.district)

But i get SQL syntax error can someone please let me know how to convert SQL to Laravel query builder format.

Comment: Edit question and Post error too.

Comment: use `DB::select()` instead of `DB::Raw()`

Comment: @er.irfankhan11 i  tried it gave me another sql error

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen Try to run your query in mysql console then put in select function

Comment: @er.irfankhan11 i ran it on the console and got the correct results. i didnt understand your previous comment could you explain what i should do

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

When use Raw query

```
   $data = DB::select('SELECT paper_id,user_id,COUNT(payments.user_id),users.district
            FROM payments
            LEFT JOIN users ON payments.user_id = users.id
            WHERE payments.paper_id='.$paper_id.'
            GROUP BY users.district HAVING 
            COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0 
            ');
```

OR

```
        $data2= DB::table('payments')->select([
            'payments.paper_id','payments.user_id','users.district',
            DB::Raw('COUNT(payments.user_id)')
            ])
            ->leftJoin('users','payments.user_id','users.id')
            ->where('payments.paper_id',$paper_id)
            ->havingRaw("COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0")
            ->groupBy('users.district')
            ->get();
```

I think `select` function should use one time only in a query, No need to add multiple time. And before add any questin alway search about your problem. Hope it will work..

For your error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055

In this file
`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php`
at this location in your laravel replace this file this for `laravel5.4`
`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,`

Comment: i tried them both but i get an error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'portal.payments.paper_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT paper_id,user_id,COUNT(payments.user_id),users.district\n
            FROM payments\n
            LEFT JOIN users ON payments.user_id = users.id\n
            WHERE payments.paper_id=3\n
            GROUP BY users.district HAVING \n
            COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0 \n
            )`

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen, I'm update the answer please look

Answer (score 0):

## Running Raw SQL Queries

```
$data = DB::select('SELECT paper_id,user_id,COUNT(payments.user_id),users.district
                FROM payments
                LEFT JOIN users ON payments.user_id = users.id
                WHERE payments.paper_id= ?
                GROUP BY users.district HAVING 
                COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0', [$paper_id]);
```

Parameter binding provides protection against SQL injection.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries

## groupBy / having

```
->select(DB::Raw('HAVING COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0'))
=>
->having(DB::Raw('COUNT(payments.user_id)'), '>=', 0)
```

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: i tried them both but i get an error   >   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'portal.payments.paper_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT paper_id,user_id,COUNT(payments.user_id),users.district\n FROM payments\n LEFT JOIN users ON payments.user_id = users.id\n WHERE payments.paper_id=3\n GROUP BY users.district HAVING \n COUNT(payments.user_id)>=0 \n )

Comment: OMG....  
Your query is incorrect.   
The columns used in the select clause must all be declared in group by.   `->groupBy('paper_id', 'user_id', 'users.district')`

Comment: Kyong-yoon Thanks a lot it works now. what i dont understand is why it ran on mysql if the query was wrong

Comment: Maybe `mysql sql-mode`.   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: no my sql-mode is deactivated. could you  upload the answer so i can close this question

Comment: Laravel 5.6 are enabled by default in strict mode.  
Did you change this setting?  
 https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php#L53